# allow app engine service account to edit calendar

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I have Google app engine Java app. I have created a service account to access Google API.

My Java app is designed to  update the Google calendar.

So I tried to share the calendar to service account email id. I am not able to choose the option 'Make changes to events' for the service account id. It defaults to 'See all event details'. Due to this, I am not able to make changes to calendar using my Java app.

I am the admin for the the google domain account that owns the calendar and the app engine. Please let me know the how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is most likely that your domain only allows at maximum read-only acls to users outside your domain. I suggest you take a look at the delegation of domain authority to service accounts, it might be what you are looking for: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation

Comment: the link is broken now